# Get the contents of one column given another column

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a tab separated file with 3 columns. I'd like to get the contents of the first column, but only for the rows where the 3rd column is equal to 8. How do I extract these values? If I just wanted to extract the values in the first column, I would do the following:

```
cat file1 | tr "\t" "~" | cut -d"~" -f1 >> file_with_column_3
```

I'm thinking something like:

```
cat file1 | tr "\t" "~" | if cut -d"~" -f3==8; then cut -d"~" -f1 ; fi>> file_with_column_3
```

But that doesn't quite seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your file is tab delimited, it seems like this problem would be well suited for `awk`.

Something simple like below should work for you, though without any sample data I can't say for sure (try to always include this on questions on SO)

```
awk -F'\t' '$3==8 {print $1}' inputfile > outputfile
```

The `-F'\t'` sets the input delimiter as tab.

`$3==8` compares if the 3rd column based on that delimiter is 8.

If so, the `{print $1}` is executed, which prints the first column.

Otherwise, nothing is done and awk proceeds to the next line.

If your file had a header you wanted to preserve, you could just modify this like the following, which tells awk to print if the current record number is 1.

```
awk -F'\t' 'NR==1 {print;} $3==8 {print $1}' inputfile > outputfile
```

Answer (score 1):

`awk` can handle this better:

```
awk -F '\t' '$3 == 8 { print $1 }' file1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with bash only too:

```
cat x | while read y; do split=(${y}); [ ${split[2]} == '8' ] && echo $split[0]; done
```

The input is read in variable `y`, then split into an array. The IFS (input field separator) defaults to `<space><tab<>newline>`, so it splits on tabs too. The third field of the array is then compared to '8'. If it equals, it prints the first field of the array. Remember that fields in arrays start counting at zero.